# Chrome Extension - Open New tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically run my extension (or a function in my extension) each time a page loads and user clicks anywhere in the page? Like open a new tab or popup.
Right now, I have it set that you would click the icon Browser Action icon to run my extension.

Comment: The questions seems broad but your starting point is a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: The short answer to this question is: "Yes". Other than that, I'm not sure how you are expecting us to answer this question.